# UITextField in UITableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield

I can't find a question like this. I searched all of the Internet but nobody ask this question. Even Apple's tutorials, there is no example. Here is my what I want to do. I want to create an app like Reminders or Wunderlist. I want to emphasize the UITextField of UITableViewCell's first cell as text input.
My first cell is a static cell which is UITextField and the other cell's are the results of UITextField. For example:

- Static cell (UITextField)
- dynamic cell (Label)
- dynamic cell (Label)
- ...

There is no button for UITextField. I want to get input from keyboard's return like Reminders.app due to I must implement UITextFieldDelegete and equalize in viewDidLoad like `textField.delagate = self`. The problem starts here. I can connect outlets in UITableViewCell (for UITextField and cells' labels) but in UITableViewCell's instance method, there is no viewDidLoad method and it disallow to use UITextFieldDelagete which can require to get input without using any button. If I use ViewController (not UITableViewController), I can easily connect outlets and use UITextFieldDelegate. How can I solve this problem? Which point I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Check Screenshot how to add any Control into UITableViewController
do not forget to change Static cell instead of dynamic prototype in tableView Property.

IBOUTLETs will connects with your ViewController , not with Custom Cell.

[image]

How to Set OUTLEts in TableViewController :
ScreenShot

[image: Simply you can do]

Please feel free to ask

Comment: Where does create textfield and label's outlets? In TableViewController or TableViewControllerCell.

Comment: wait. i am adding another screenshot

Comment: Any custom class connection from Identity inspector? You will leave empty in custom class.

Comment: Extra Point  : to create registration form you can use TableViewController if you don want to use Scroll View.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114420/discussion-between-mathema-and-krutarth-patel).